# How to Stop Wordpress Change Slug Automatically Same as Title When Publish?

Tags: permalinks, urls, slug

How to Stop WordPress Change Slug Automatically Same as Title When Publish?

I am optimizing my old content and editing all Old Posts, But when our writers click on publish WordPress (contributor role user) change the URL/Permalink to a new Title

This problem only in the contributor user role when the user post publish for review

See The Screenshot to explain

Before Click on Publish

[image: Before click on publish]

After Click on Publish WordPress change slug Url

[image]

How to stop Wordpress to do this?

Comment: you need to set it manually to something, then WordPress won't change it

Comment: many times I set my slug, but when the contributor user edits content and submits for review, WordPress changes the slug again. it only happens when posts submit for review